# Why I can not connect to Oracle 10g from a PHP program?

Tags: php, database, oracle, database-connection

I am using `Oracle 1Og` express edition and `EasyPHP` v5.3.5.0

My oracle database in running on port 8080.

I can not connect the oracle database using my php program.

I am confused about the 3rd parameter of the oci_connect statement.
Here is my code.

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect("scott", "tiger","localhost/XE");
if (!$conn) 
{
   $m = oci_error();
   echo $m['message'], "\n";
   exit;
}
else 
{
   print "Connected to Oracle!";
}

oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: What information does `echo '<pre>'.print_r(oci_error(), true).'</pre>';` produce?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.5.0\www\Database_connection\add.php on line 16

Comment: Which one is line #16? Your code has only 14 lines.

Comment: This the output after adding that previous line...what to do??

Comment: Sorry...In main code there was some comment lines....Now it is shown that it is on line 15

Comment: Line 15 has the statement oci_close($conn);

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this method instead? (granted you know your tnsnames entry)

```
<?php
    $tns = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)))" ;

    if($conn = OCILogon("scott", "tiger", $tns))
    {
        echo “Connected.\n”;
        OCILogoff($conn);
    }
    else
    {
        $err = OCIError();
        echo “Connection ERR.” . $err[text] . "\n";
    }
?>
```